# Controlling iOS audio source volumes while staying in the same avAudioSession Category

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

Our app requires our avAudioSession to be enabled constantly. However, we are looking for a way to use .duckOthers or similar function to lower background audio sources intermittently. We have tried changing audio categories in order to accomplish this but it leaves us with undesirable transitions and delays. Is there another way to periodically lower the volume of sound coming from outside sources while our avAudioSession is permanently enabled? Ideally, we would like to tie it to a bool.